# jQuery: How to remove() multiple elements in an array from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many elements to remove and I want to to group them into one function, so I have array such as:

```
var removeArr = ['.someClass1','.someClass2','#someID'];
```

How do I use the remove function on each elements of this array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is an array use can create an [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) using [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) can call [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) on it

```
$(removeArr.join(',')).remove()
```